# Is it possible to create a custom namespace tag in XMP Dublin core metadata?

Tags: metadata, xmp, exiftool, dublin-core

I am curious to know whether it is possible to create a custom namespace for the [XMP Dublin Core metadata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dublin_Core)?

For example If I want to add a tag like `mytest`

I can write the XMP Metadata standard tags such as `description` however I can't write my own tag

```
~/$ exiftool -xmp-dc:description="Foo" demo.png
    1 image files updated
~/$ exiftool -xmp-dc:mytest="Bar" demo.png
Warning: Tag 'mytest' does not exist
Nothing to do.
```

Comment: Do you want a custom *namespace* or an additional *property/tag*?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes.  Defining custom XMP tags and namespaces in ExifTool is done via user-defined tags in a config file.  For example:

```
~/$ exiftool -config my.config -xmp-dc:mytest="Bar" demo.png
    1 image files updated
~/$ exiftool -xmp-dc:mytest demo.png
Mytest                          : Bar
~/$ cat my.config
%Image::ExifTool::UserDefined = (
    'Image::ExifTool::XMP::dc' => {
        mytest => { },
    },
);
# end
```

See the [sample ExifTool config file](http://owl.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/config.html) for more details.